# How can I print string values individually?

Tags: string, lightbox

If my string is like

```
String result="netbeans,eclipse,maven";
```

I need an output as r1=netbeans r2=eclipse r3=maven 
like that how can I print this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
    List<string>values = result.Split(",".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
    foreach(string str in values){
      Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

More Info: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)